# how can i exec a python-file WITH imports in PHP?

Tags: python, php

Im very new to python and i was not able to find 100% fitting answer here :-/

I made a python-script with a list of imports (os, pyplot, pandas, tensorflow ..) now i would like to run this script on a webserver and exec it with PHP.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python scripts/XXX.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

so far no problem for a simple hello world.
but how i can handle the imports? Im using Visual Studio code, i dont find a export function to export with all libraries, i just can do a default "save as", i also trieds to save as .bat

whats the best way to get a python file executeable with PHP and those list of imports?
i just wanna pass 3 vars and get the output

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps as a reference.

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: thanks! Yes, for the args. But how i can handle "import os" "import tensorflow"? Should i build an EXE? is this the way to get the imports into my file? thanks